# Div appear onclick, disappear onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(function() {
  $('.dropTitle').click(function() {
    $('.columnCenter ul ul').css('display', 'block');
  });
                              
});
```

I have a click function here. When I click .dropTitle, .columnCenter ul ul displays 'block'. How can I have it where once I click .dropTitle again, it will switch to display:none;?

I want to be able switch back and forth between display:block to display:none upon clicking .dropTitle.

All help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `toggle`:

```
$(function() {
    $('.dropTitle').click(function() {
        $('.columnCenter ul ul').toggle();
    });                        
});
```

[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/hs9w1u3o/)

Comment: I have 0 experience with javascript, can you send me the complete code including the display:none, display:block results?

Comment: I tried it. When I click .dropTitle again, columnCenter ul ul is not disappearing, but it does appear

Comment: Then there is something wrong in your code. I created you an example: https://jsfiddle.net/hs9w1u3o/ @miksham

Comment: One thing i forgot to mention, i have .columnCenter ul ul set as 'display:none' in my css (it's necessary)...is that the issue? essentially once i click droptitle, i was columncenter to appear, then disappear upon click, btw thanks SO MUCH for helping me with this

Comment: It works! :D one last thing...what appears is a dropdown menu, do you know what to add to the code to make the menu (columncenter ul ul) disappear upon click anywhere outside of the menu? if you can update me with a jsfiddle that would be great

Comment: You can do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hs9w1u3o/2/. In the example you can only close it when you click on the red box. @miksham

Comment: I might be asking too much but would you know how to do it where if click anything outside of columnCenter ul ul (not just within the contains of the red box), it'll disapper? Regardless, I will be checking your question as the best answer

Comment: Actually nevermind, managed to solve it. Thanks so much again, eisbehr! :)

Answer (score 0):

it would probably be easier to use a utility class here, for example:

```
.is--hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

and then toggle that class on click:

```
$('.dropTitle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('is--hidden')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would not only use `.toggle()` but I'd use `.on()` as well...

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.droptitle', function() {
        $('.columnCenter ul ul').toggle();
    });                        
});
```

Comment: And why would you register the listener on the whole document live? That is overhead ... and where is your `display` variable is coming from?!

Comment: I left the 'display' as part of a mistake -- I have removed it .. As far as making the document listener .. JS is already listening, you are just instructing it that you want it to REACT to it ..  I'd love to see your benchmarks proving otherwise ..